# how to convert externalXML to arraylist in FLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

only those xml tag  having data need to be placed in an arraylist ,which will act as a dataprovider for a datagroup.

Can anyone pls help in achieving this task...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
for each (var x:XML in myXML.item) { 
    if (x.children().length() > 0)
        myList.push(x);
}
```